# Is it possible to get the version released by semantic release in github actions?

Tags: github-actions, semantic-release

I am using github actions for my project and to release I am using semantic release, Once semantic release releases the version Is it possible to forward that version to next steps?

```
  release:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: |
          git pull
          npm install
      - name: semanticRelease
        run: npx semantic-release -t \${version}
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
  update-release:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Update release
        uses: tubone24/update_release@v1.2.0
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
          TAG_NAME: # I need the tag released by semantic release in the prev step here. If no release is done I need to skip this step.
        with:
          is_append_body: true
          body: "Update something"
```

Comment: https://github.community/t/sharing-a-variable-between-jobs/16967 https://github.com/phish108/action-experiments/issues/1

Comment: Here the issue is not with the sharing the output between the steps, I was not able the get the current released tag version from semantic release.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the command `semantic-release` with `--dry-run` argument to just print the next release and then pass it to your next step.

something like this :

```yaml
  release:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      new_tag_version: ${{ steps.tag_version.outputs.new_tag_version }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: |
          npm install

      - name: Dry run to get the next release version
        id: tag_version
        run: |
          export NEXT_TAG_VERSION=$(npx semantic-release --dry-run | grep 'The next release version is' | sed -E 's/.* ([[:digit:].]+)$/\1/')
          echo "new_tag_version=${NEXT_TAG_VERSION}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

      - name: semanticRelease
        run: npx semantic-release -t \${version}
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

  update-release:
    needs: release
    if: ${{ needs.release.outputs.new_tag_version != '' }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Update release
        uses: tubone24/update_release@v1.2.0
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
          TAG_NAME: ${{ needs.release.outputs.new_tag_version }}
        with:
          is_append_body: true
          body: "Update something"
```

I added an if condition in the second step to only run when the variable new_tag_version is not empty